# How to stop resubmit form data after refreshing jsp page in struts1

Tags: jsp, struts1

I have problem, after refreshing the jsp. when i call refresh (F5) button after submitting the form. the data saved repeatedly after calling refresh button every time.

Answer (score 2):

1.To prevent this use ajax option for submit.

OR

2.use REDIRECT option and redirect page after form submission.

**What happend when you submit the form to server**

By clicking the "submit" button on a form sends a request to the web server, which includes all the data entered on the form. Not only the URL but also the form data is part of the request, and this request is remembered by the browser. If the user clicks "refresh", the browser repeats the request, sending the same URL and form data to the web server again.

Forms can be submitted in two ways, GET or POST.GET request has no side-effects; it only fetches data but does not make any changes to the database.In other way, if a request changes data like insert,update,delete operations then it should be a POST.

**The most important difference is that browsers will warn the user if they try to repeat a POST -- clicking "refresh" will pop up a dialog box warning the user** 
that this may cause an operation to be repeated, and confirming that they really want to resubmit. The browser does not show this confirmation when refreshing a GET request.

If your form using the GET method,changing it to POST is the simplest solution, since this will at least mean that the user is warned if they try to refresh.

But a better solution is the POST+REDIRECT+GET.For more http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Answer (score 0):

Use well known `PRG pattern`. For more info have a look here: [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get)

Or a simpler solution is while sending control from your `Action class` add one `request attribute`, while coming on JSp check for that particular request attribute, If it is there: redirect the control to your same JSp page.

**Logic behind this: Explanation:**
When redirect is happening it makes an anonymous request to browser without any output, then browser makes an implicit request to targeted resource. Thus while redirecting your request goes through one round-trip from browser, that's the reason your previous `request & response` objects are destroyed and a new request(Made from browser implicitly) is generated and new requested object is created by container. So your previous request attribute will not be there. Means your previous data also will not be there. Then from next time onwards while you will refresh the JSP page nothing will happen.